# Check if a variable is empty/null/undefined

Tags: javascript, cypress, chai

This code block is used to read an excel file and get user data by a given user role.

But if the user role does not exist in the excel file, it will return an undefined value.

How to de we check that the `user` variable is not undefined or null?

```js
 cy.task('getExcelData', Cypress.env('usersFilePath')).then((users) => {
            const user = users.find(user => {
                return user.userRole === 'userRole';
            });
    
            cy.wrap(user).should('not.be.empty');
            cy.wrap(user).should('not.be.a',undefined)
            cy.wrap(user).should('not.be.a',null)
            signIn(user.username, user.password);
        });
```

`cy.wrap(user).should('not.be.empty')` (this part working but not others)

This is the error I received:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see chaijs  [.a(type[, msg])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a)

> Asserts that the target’s type is equal to the given **string type**. Types are case insensitive.
>
> ```js
> expect(undefined).to.be.an('undefined')
> ```

The `.a()` or `.an()` is doing a `typeof` check that returns a string, so you just need to quote the `"undefined"` type

```js
cy.wrap(user).should('not.be.a', "undefined")
```

or drop the `.a` to do a reference check instead

```js
cy.wrap(user).should('not.be', undefined)
```

Comment: `cy.wrap(user).should('not.eq', undefined)` would also work, right?

Comment: I think `not.be` and `not.eq` are synonyms, at least the assertions are quite similar.

Comment: You could only use `not.eq` for `undefined`, but not other types, because the value happens to be the same as the type.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check the result of searching the users array, do it outside the `.find()` function.

If no user with the required role is found, the `.find()` function returns `undefined` (never null or empty string or empty array).

Ref [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
cy.task('getExcelData', Cypress.env('usersFilePath')).then((users) => {

  /* 
    e.g users = [
      { userRole: 'admin', username: '...', password: '...' },
      { userRole: 'userRole', username: '...', password: '...' },
    ]
  */

  const user = users.find(user => user.userRole === 'userRole')
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('user is undefined')
  }

  signIn(user.username, user.password);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty, null, and undefined values are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) so you can throw an error if not truthy.

```js
cy.task('getExcelData', Cypress.env('usersFilePath')).then((users) => {
            const user = users.find(user => {
                if(!user) {
                   throw new Error('user is empty, null, or undefined', user)
                }

                return user.userRole === 'userRole';
            });
                signIn(user.username, user.password);
        });
```